# Scene Transition in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

How can I make transition between stages in libgdx ?

I have 2 screens MenuScreen and GameScreen each of which has a stage

I write the following to make a transition :

in MenuScreen

```
SequenceAction sequenceAction = new SequenceAction();
sequenceAction.addAction(Actions.moveTo(-Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0, 4.0f));
sequenceAction.addAction(Actions.run(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        gameMain.setScreen(new GameScreen(gameMain));
             }
     }));
stage.getRoot().addAction(sequenceAction);
```

in GameScreen

```
stage.getRoot().setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), 0);
stage.getRoot().addAction(Actions.moveTo(0, 0, 4.0f));
```

but the problem is GameScreen does not following MenuScreen directly
i.e it wait until MenuScreen has completely gone from screen and I want them to move at the same time

Comment: Unfortunately due to the way screens work, only one can be rendered at a time. This means that it is not possible to briefly draw both at any single time. One solution would be to take a screenshot of one of the screens before the transition and pass it to the next screen so it can complete the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different kinds of transition.  To concretely answer this question clarify which kind of transition you are looking for.

If you want to do a blended transition, you'll need to render a single frame of the old scene to a buffer, render a single frame of the new scene to a buffer, and then do the transition animation.  Here's a pointer for the [FrameBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551669/libgdx-spritebatch-render-to-texture).

A simpler strategy is probably to just fade to black on the old scene, then fade in from black on the new scene.

Comment: as you said I want to fade out the current screen and fade in the next one
How can I do this ?
I see a class by someone which makes the transition between the current and next screen but I see this can't be applied as I can't render next screen without show method (it gives me NullPointerException)
or I can make the transition by passing a screenshot of previous screen to next screen
What do you think ?

Comment: http://blog.gemserk.com/2012/03/05/implementing-transitions-between-screens/

Comment: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11092